# Retrieve all installed packages and their versions from nodes

Tags: puppet

I use puppet to manage package installations on a number of nodes. These nodes are used as software testing environments. It happens that packages are uninstalled during software tests or their version might change, depending on the test scenario.

Is it possible to retrieve a list of all currently installed packages on each of my nodes? A "snapshot" of the whole testing environment, so to say.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Facter 2`, you can create a [custom fact](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/custom_facts.html) that hands a hash structure to the master, e.g. `package-name => package-version`.

With `PuppetDB`, you can store all those fact values and retrieve them via the [API](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppetdb/latest/api/query/curl.html#using-curl-from-localhost-non-sslhttp).

Comment: I was thinking about it, but the sheer size of this hash scares me a little. A CentOS-7 box can easily have over a 1000 packages installed, for example. Is that not a concern -- both for the node and for the Puppet-master receiving facter-data from hundreds of such nodes?

Comment: @MikhailT. Yes, there will be performance implications. If possible, try it outside of production first. If you don't want it to hamper Puppet's daily business, setting up a distinct master (including DB) for this might still be easier than rolling your own data warehouse solution.

Comment: I, actually, implemented such a "fact" here -- but it is limited to versions of the explicitly "white-listed" packages only.